# wp-tinymce.php 404

Tags: 404-error, tinymce

My visual editor isn't working on a site after just launching it to a new server. I assumed a permissions issue, but the file itself is set to 644. I tried 755 on it as well and still no go. The directories all the way up are 755.

I can access other files in the directory, but not this one file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`wp-tinymce.php` loads to the WordPress dashboard using Ajax on your end.

So the permission for that file should be 664. 
But the problem is your `/wp-include` folder may not allow remote PHP execution. This may be either in .htaccess via some security plugin you are using or somewhere in Nginx rules.

Further, I think you are using some plugin that calls wp-tinymce.php in a strange way.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by the .htaccess placed in the wp-includes folder by iThemes Security as a hardening measure. That file *might* be invisible to you depending on your FTP client's settings.

I've personally seen it happen with iThemes Security v6.2.1 on WP 4.8 on php 7.0